# How to draw attention to question without flags and close votes?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, flags

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240394/copy-and-paste-layers-doesnt-work-in-illustrator-cs6). **It has nothing to do with programming.** But sadly nobody except me has viewed it.

[image: Viewed 3 times]

- I could **flag** it, but I ran out of flags for today.
- I could **vote to close**, but I can't yet.

What should I do in this situation to draw community attention to the question so it will be closed and deleted?

Comment: It's ten minutes old, give it time. That being said, the problem is not off-topic questions being there, it's off-topic questions taking up attention off other questions that deserve it more. So to answer your question: give it as little attention as possible.

Comment: There are 10 million _non-deleted_ questions on the site. Just wait for tomorrow to flag it, or wait for someone else to take care of it (community members or the roomba).

Comment: The meta effect has taken care of it now

Comment: Flagging is the right thing to do here. If you've run out of flags, you've really run out of the ability to help deal with off-topic questions. I recognize and appreciate that you still want to help, but there is really no good way for you to continue doing so until your flags are refilled. The good news is, if you consistently raise helpful flags, the number of flags you have available per-day will increase, so you'll be able to do more good!

Answer (score 1):

There are chat rooms.

for example SOCVR.

add it there in the format

```
[tag:cv-pls] reason link
```